# adding a quotation mark to the beginning and end of a record in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script that generates an array of values from a POST

```
$values = array_values($_POST);
```

What I'd like to do is add a single quote  '  to the beginning AND the end of each record in the array.

```
hint: $values = "'".$values."'";   does not work
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

for example if the array contains   [nameFirst] => Vik [nameLast] => Grant 
it would replace it with  [nameFirst] => 'Vik' [nameLast] => 'Grant'

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.php.net/array_map

```
$new_values = array_map( function($value) {
    return "'{$value}'";
}, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = "'{$value}'";
}
```